# Why do i have debian-sys-maint instead of a mysql root user?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I am currently trying to get mysql setup and i was trying to recover the password because i didnt know my root password and i got these directions

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -u root mysql
 mysql>UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('PASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
 sudo killall mysqld
 sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

the problem is whwn i log into the mysql i notice that when i do

```
 mysql> select * from user;
```

i only have 1 user that is debian-sys-maint, So how do i not have a root user and how do i create one with a password

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is using [pluggable authentication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/pluggable-authentication.html). It means that there could be users allowed to connect even if they are not in `users` table. So if you have default installation of MySQL in Ubuntu, just connect as root with root's password. MySQL will use Linux's authentication to check for password. Neverthel ["resetting permissions"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix). And concerning the `debian-sys-maint` user, read [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/9948/what-is-the-debian-sys-maint-mysql-user-and-more/9952#9952) on serverfault.